# Notion of group generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

I'm asking myself what the meaning of a statement like the following is:

> Let $G$ be a group and $T_i \subseteq G$ be a family of subgroups of $G$ indexed by a possibly infinite set $I$. Now let $H$ be another group *generated* by $T_i, i\in I$.

As I understand the above is, that there is a **surjective** group homorphism

$$\prod_{i \in I} T_i \twoheadrightarrow H,$$

because every element in $H$ comes from some product of elements in $T_i$.

But consider the following case where $H'$ is another group:
Let $\varphi$ be an **injective** group homomorphism

$$\varphi: H' \hookrightarrow \prod_{i\in I} T_i$$

My first question now is:

> Is it correct to say that $H'$ is generated by the $T_i$?

Secondly, is in which case can we talk about $\prod_{i \in I} T_i$ being the **free product** over $I$?

Thank you, Tom

Comment: This is actually a comment but I have not enough reputation for giving one. I think that $H$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains each of the $T_{i}$. If for instance $T_i=T$ (they all coincide) then $H=T$.

Answer (score 1):

As @H.B. said, $H$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains each of the $T_i$. There is *not* necessarily a surjective homomorphism $\phi: \prod T_i \to H$.  If you replace $\prod T_i$ with $\oplus T_i$, and you add the assumption that $t_i t_j =  t_j t_i$ for all $t_i \in T_i, t_j \in T_j, i \ne j$, then there is a canonical surjective homomorphism $\phi$ (if $|I| = 2$, this is given by $(t_1, t_2) \mapsto t_1 t_2)$.  However, without this commutativity condition, $\phi$ will definitely not be a homomorphism, and might not be surjective as a set map.

As examples, consider $G = S_3$.  In one example, $T_1$ is generated by $(1 2)$, and $T_2$ is generated by $(1 2 3)$.  In the second example, $T_1$ is generated by $(1 2)$ and $T_2$ is generated by $(1 3)$.  In both cases, $H = G$.  In the first example, $\phi$ is surjective but not a homomorphism.  In the second example, $\phi$ isn't even surjective, and it had no hope of being surjective since $ 6 = |H| > |T_1 \times T_2| = 4$.